# TcpListener stop working when the program is open by a Windows Service

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-services, tcpclient, tcplistener

I write a program that listen a tcp port and read the incoming packet.

If I open the program with double-click it works fine and report 31 bytes (the correct amount).

If I open the program with another application it report 9 bytes (that are completely different from the 31 bytes) even if I start the program as admin user:

```
Process.Start(programPath);
```

or with admin permission:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = programPath;
programPath += "\\Save Log.exe";
process.StartInfo.FileName = programPath;
process.StartInfo.Domain = "MY-DOMAIN";
process.StartInfo.UserName = "Account";
process.StartInfo.Password = password;
process.Start();
```

Comment: You need to post the code that is using TcpListener.  That's where the problem occurs, after all.

Comment: I use System.Net and System.Net.Socket and i try 3 different ways to catch the packet but they all have the same problem